# Compiling a single coffeescript file breaks the asset pipeline rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I was getting non-descriptive errors from coffeescript in my rails project, so I compiled a single file to narrow down the line number that was causing the problem:

coffee -c app/assets/javascripts/myfile.coffee

Now every time I edit and save that file, the changes actually don't propagate to the browser.

I tried deleting the /tmp folder and public/assets folder as well, but that did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you say this:

```
coffee -c app/assets/javascripts/myfile.coffee
```

`coffee` will produce a JavaScript in:

```
app/assets/javascripts/myfile.js
```

Presumably the `myfile.js` that you generated is hiding the `.coffee` file or interfering with the usual `.coffee` to `.js` compilation.

Try deleting the stray `myfile.js`.